# WPF CommandBinding for App menu with Gestures

Tags: wpf, gesture, commandbinding

I have a sample WPF app that I am trying to get the App level menus with KeyGestures working.
This is working fine if I have my app menu in the MainWindow.

Here is my Window Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWpfApp.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWpfApp"
    Name="RootWindow"
    Title="Window2" Height="600" Width="800">
<!--<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+N" Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.New}" />
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+F1" Command="{x:Static local:Window2.ShowHelp}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New"
              Executed="NewExecuted"
              CanExecute="NewCanExecute"/>
    <CommandBinding x:Name="HelpCmdBinding" CanExecute="AltHelpCanExecute" Executed="AltHelpExecuted" Command="{x:Static local:Window2.ShowHelp}" />
</Window.CommandBindings>-->
<DockPanel>
    <!--<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N" Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.New}" />
            <MenuItem Header="E_xit" InputGestureText="Alt+F4" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Help">
            <MenuItem Header="_View Help" InputGestureText="Ctrl+F1" Command="{x:Static local:Window2.ShowHelp}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_About" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>-->
    <local:TopMenu DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <ContentControl>

    </ContentControl>
</DockPanel>
```

In the above code, all commented are my first try which works fine.

When I moved my Menu to TopMenu control I have an issue. Gestures don't fire the call.

Here is my code behind.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for TopMenu.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class TopMenu : UserControl
{
    public static RoutedCommand ShowHelp = new RoutedCommand("AltHelp", typeof(TopMenu));

    public TopMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    void NewExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The " + ((RoutedCommand)e.Command).Name + " command invoked on " + ((FrameworkElement)target).Name);
    }
    void NewCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    void AltHelpExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The " + ((RoutedCommand)e.Command).Name + " command invoked on " + ((FrameworkElement)target).Name);
    }
    void AltHelpCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }


}

<UserControl x:Class="SampleWpfApp.TopMenu"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWpfApp"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+N" Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.New}" />
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+F1" Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New"
              Executed="NewExecuted"
              CanExecute="NewCanExecute"/>
    <CommandBinding x:Name="HelpCmdBinding" CanExecute="AltHelpCanExecute" Executed="AltHelpExecuted" Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N" Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.New}" />
            <MenuItem Header="E_xit" InputGestureText="Alt+F4" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Help">
            <MenuItem Header="_View Help" InputGestureText="Ctrl+F1" Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_About" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

What is the issue here when I moved the code to the UserControl? FYI, after I moved the code ApplicationCommands.New does not work at all even when I click the menu.

Note: For the first working version you have to move the code from TopMenu to Window2 codebehind, uncomment all commented Xaml, comment `<local:TopMenu DockPanel.Dock="Top" />`

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the answer. If anyone has a better way of doing please advise.

I had to add this code to the main window. The CommandTarget is the one which forwards it to the TopMenu.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+N" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=TopMenu}" />
        <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+F1" Command="{x:Static local:TopMenu.ShowHelp}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=TopMenu}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

Thanks for your time.

This is what gave me the answer but I did it in Xaml.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/753c2a0b-753f-43d3-afb3-01d4d3c93787/